# Django force user to fill out form on login

Tags: python, django

I need to have certain users fill out a specific form on login. Django should redirect the user to the form, whenever a certain condition is `True` for that user.

I used a custom middleware to do it, but I am curious if there is a better approach.

Any ideas?

Comment: That doesn't work :/ Still getting too many redirects. And why is this marked as duplicate? Can you post the link to the duplicate question?

Comment: Never mind, I found it! Thanks, I was able to solve my issue. However, I am still curious if there is a nicer way of doing this.

Comment: Edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The middleware is the way to go for this problem, it's the only method that's truly reliable and configurable.

Comment: Alright thanks, just needed a little bit of external approval for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to change [`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url) to a view that does the check and redirects if required. However, users can then navigate away from the form by typing in another url.

If you absolutely require users to fill out the form, then using middleware is the way to do it.

Comment: LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL isn't really the use case, but thanks for your input!